# max() function stops for loop

Tags: for-loop, set, max, python-3.8

I don't know why but for loop after printing max value from array does not work. But if I remove  `print(max(arr))` it works fine.

Input:

```
3 3 3 34 5
```

Code:

```
arr = map(int, set(input().split()))

print(max(arr))

for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

Expected output:

```
34
3
34
5
```

Output:

```
34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exhausted the iterator returned from `map()`. Instead, create a list from the `map()`:

```py
arr = list(map(int, set(input().split())))  # <-- add list() around map()

print(max(arr))

for i in arr:
    print(i)
```

Prints (for example):

```
3 3 3 34 5
34
5
3
34
```